# error linking to 32bit boost library with g++

Tags: boost, linker, g++

I am making a project in Mac OSX and use the boost compiled libraries (serialisation amongst others). I installed all my dependencies as x86_64 libraries, but now want to make explicitly 32 bit ones (i386) and recompile my project for 32bit users.

I have recompiled by libraries with `g++ -m32` where appropriate and then re made 32 bit boost libraries using

```
./bootstrap.sh link=static
./b2 cflags=-m32 cxxflags=-m32 address-model=32 threading=multi architecture=x86 instruction-set=i686
```

I then recompile my project by explicitly linking to the 32 bit libraries. So something like

```
g++ file.cpp /usr/local/lib/boost_i386/libboost_serialization.a -m32 -o executable
```

where the library is explicitly the 32 bit version verified by using `otool` as follows with (partial) output (all list cputype as i386)

```
otool -hv -arch all libboost_serialization.a
Archive : libboost_serialization.a
libboost_serialization.a(basic_archive.o):
Mach header
      magic cputype cpusubtype  caps    filetype ncmds sizeofcmds      flags
   MH_MAGIC    I386        ALL  0x00      OBJECT     3       1180 SUBSECTIONS_VIA_SYMBOLS
```

However, when I compile my project (despite most dependencies working fine), it trips up and that symbols are missing for this architecture

Explicitly:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "boost::archive::detail::shared_ptr_helper::shared_ptr_helper()", referenced from:
      boost::archive::binary_iarchive::binary_iarchive(std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, unsigned int)in ccCH1ama.o
  "boost::archive::detail::shared_ptr_helper::~shared_ptr_helper()", referenced from:
      boost::archive::binary_iarchive::~binary_iarchive()in ccCH1ama.o
      boost::archive::binary_iarchive::~binary_iarchive()in ccCH1ama.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have explicitly built the 32bit libraries, checked they are in fact 32 bit, and explicitly linked to them, I don't know what else to do. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the header files were boost v1.55 but the i386 libraries used the most current version v1.57. This caused the error. Building the libraries with the older v1.55 to match the headers fixed the problem.